# Nonlinear equations and unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

How to show that the following system of equations has a unique solution $(x,y)$? $x,y$ are scalars.

$x+\frac{3}{4}y+\frac{1}{20}\sin x=0$

$-\frac{37}{40}x+y+\frac{1}{10}\sin y=0$

I tried contraction mapping, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does the system have an algebraic solution in $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Actually, I am asking the uniqueness. $x=y=0$ is a solution.

Comment: I understood I meant actually what bogus suggested as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the top equation for $y$, substituted it into the second equation, and got
$$\frac{1}{10}\sin(\frac{1}{15}\sin x + \frac{4}{3}x) + \frac{271}{120}x + \frac{1}{15}\sin x = 0$$.  One solution is $x = 0$, as you found.  The derivative of the left-hand side is always positive:

$$\frac{1}{10}\cos(\frac{1}{15}\sin x + \frac{4}{3}x)(\frac{1}{15}\cos x+\frac{4}{3})+\frac{271}{120} +\frac{1}{15}\cos x \geq -\frac{1}{10}(\frac{1}{15} + \frac{4}{3}) + \frac{271}{120} - \frac{1}{15} > 0$$.

So $0$ is the only solution for $x$, and $y$ has to be $0$ too.

It is late and I don't guarantee against errors in the fractions, but I think the procedure works.

Comment: I think the $\frac{1}{15}$ in your lower bound (inside the parentheses) should be $\frac{-1}{15}$, since the min of cos is $-1.$ But the lower bound still comes out positive: $+413/200$.

Comment: @coffemath : the "worst case" occurs when $\cos x  = +1$, which is why there is $\frac{1}{15}$ inside the parentheses.

Comment: I also solved the problem using the Contraction Mapping Theorem, using the distance $d(<a,b>,<c,d>) = |a-c| +|b-d|$ and rewriting the equations as $f(<x,y>) = <-\frac{3}{4}y - \frac{1}{20}\sin x, \frac{37}{40}x-\frac{1}{10}\sin y>$.  $f$ is a contraction with $\lambda = \frac{39}{40}$.